# Computing a confusion matrix using a Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

I need to compute the confusion matrix of the Naive Bayes classifier using multinomial distributions for each variable in the `wbca` dataset by doing leave-one-out cross validation in R.

As a note, the prior probability of sampling a malignant tumor is π0 = 1/3, and the prior probability for sampling a benign tumor is π1 = 2/3. I have no idea where to begin as I'm pretty new to machine learning.

The way I think I should approach this is first implement the Naive Bayes classifier, then perform LOOCV, and then compute the confusion matrix. I'm not sure if this is correct, and if it is, then I don't know how to write it out in code.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think naivebayes package allows the multinomial predictors, so try something like below, where the LOOCV is roughly implemented:

```
library(faraway)
library(naivebayes)
library(caret)

predictors = !grepl("Class",colnames(wbca))
label = "Class"

res = lapply(1:nrow(wbca),function(i){
fit = multinomial_naive_bayes(y=factor(wbca[-i,label]),
x=as.matrix(wbca[-i,predictors]),prior=c(1/3,2/3))
data.frame(label=wbca[i,label],
pred = predict(fit,as.matrix(wbca[i,predictors],nrow=1))
)
})

res = do.call(rbind,res)

confusionMatrix(factor(res$label,levels=0:1),res$pred)

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   0   1
         0 197  41
         1  20 423

               Accuracy : 0.9104          
                 95% CI : (0.8864, 0.9308)
    No Information Rate : 0.6814          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2e-16         

                  Kappa : 0.7989          

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.01045         

            Sensitivity : 0.9078          
            Specificity : 0.9116          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.8277          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.9549          
             Prevalence : 0.3186          
         Detection Rate : 0.2893          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.3495          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.9097          

       'Positive' Class : 0
```